# How to assign ip to Hyper-V VM with Host's Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am making a web panel to manage my hyper-v.

I want to manage IP locally with my panel, but windows basic hyper-v powershell option doesn't have assign IP function.

How can I assign an IP to Hyper-V VM with Host's Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with using this script:

```
Function Set-VMNetworkConfiguration {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=1,
                   ParameterSetName='DHCP',
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=0,
                   ParameterSetName='Static',
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMNetworkAdapter]$NetworkAdapter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=1,
                   ParameterSetName='Static')]
        [String[]]$IPAddress=@(),

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   Position=2,
                   ParameterSetName='Static')]
        [String[]]$Subnet=@(),

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   Position=3,
                   ParameterSetName='Static')]
        [String[]]$DefaultGateway = @(),

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   Position=4,
                   ParameterSetName='Static')]
        [String[]]$DNSServer = @(),

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   Position=0,
                   ParameterSetName='DHCP')]
        [Switch]$Dhcp
    )

    $VM = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2' -Class 'Msvm_ComputerSystem' | Where-Object { $_.ElementName -eq $NetworkAdapter.VMName } 
    $VMSettings = $vm.GetRelated('Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData') | Where-Object { $_.VirtualSystemType -eq 'Microsoft:Hyper-V:System:Realized' }    
    $VMNetAdapters = $VMSettings.GetRelated('Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPortSettingData') 

    $NetworkSettings = @()
    foreach ($NetAdapter in $VMNetAdapters) {
        if ($NetAdapter.Address -eq $NetworkAdapter.MacAddress) {
            $NetworkSettings = $NetworkSettings + $NetAdapter.GetRelated("Msvm_GuestNetworkAdapterConfiguration")
        }
    }

    $NetworkSettings[0].IPAddresses = $IPAddress
    $NetworkSettings[0].Subnets = $Subnet
    $NetworkSettings[0].DefaultGateways = $DefaultGateway
    $NetworkSettings[0].DNSServers = $DNSServer
    $NetworkSettings[0].ProtocolIFType = 4096

    if ($dhcp) {
        $NetworkSettings[0].DHCPEnabled = $true
    } else {
        $NetworkSettings[0].DHCPEnabled = $false
    }

    $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class "Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService" -Namespace "root\virtualization\v2"
    $setIP = $Service.SetGuestNetworkAdapterConfiguration($VM, $NetworkSettings[0].GetText(1))

    if ($setip.ReturnValue -eq 4096) {
        $job=[WMI]$setip.job 

        while ($job.JobState -eq 3 -or $job.JobState -eq 4) {
            start-sleep 1
            $job=[WMI]$setip.job
        }

        if ($job.JobState -eq 7) {
            write-host "Success"
        }
        else {
            $job.GetError()
        }
    } elseif($setip.ReturnValue -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Success"
    }
}
```